# Newbie: WebDav mounted drive

Tags: webdav

(I am using Linux Mint)

I have set up a WebDav mounted drive to my Google Drive account.

My question is: does a mounted drive take up local disk space, or is it like a virtual drive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storage is remote, but it uses a local cache.
Before you can dismount the cache needs to be written.